# Test whether an interval contains integer points

Tags: algorithms, logic

I want to make a non-complex (for algorithmic implementation) logical condition to test whether some real interval contains any integer points.

Let $x$ be an interval with bounds $l, r$;

Let $LI(x)$ be a predicate that holds if $x$'s left boundary is inclusive and $RI(x)$ be a predicate that holds if $x$'s right boundary is inclusive.

Finally, let $P(x)$ be a predicate which holds if $x$ does contain at least one integer point.

Here's what I have produced so far:

$P(x) \equiv (\lfloor l \rfloor + 1 < r) \lor (RI(x) \land (r \in \mathbb Z) ) \lor (LI(x) \land (l \in \mathbb Z))$

Is this insufficient or superfluous?
Can anyone make up a better formula?
Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the $|x| \gt 1$ clause, as the next will take care of that case

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** fixing condition for the open set using proposal in comments.

Given that the interval $x$ is not empty, the open interval $(l,r)$ contains an integer if and only if:

$$\lfloor l \rfloor + 2 \leq \lceil r \rceil$$

Otherwise, the only way for an integer to be in the interval is if one of the boundaries is closed, and that value is an integer.  That is:

$$(LI(x) \land \lfloor l \rfloor = l) \lor (RI(x) \land \lceil r \rceil=r)$$

I use floor and ceiling here just to be cute - so we only need to compute $\lceil r \rceil$ and $\lfloor l \rfloor$.

So the full expression is:
$$(\lfloor l \rfloor + 2 \leq \lceil r \rceil) \lor$$
$$(LI(x) \land \lfloor l \rfloor = l) \lor $$
$$(RI(x) \land \lceil r \rceil=r)$$

If you need the condition that $x$ is not empty, then $\land$ the above expression with $$l\lt r \lor (l = r \land LI(x) \land RI(x))$$

Comment: There's a problem with the open interval condition you lead off with.  Nonempty open interval $(1,2)$ does not contain an integer, but the ceiling of 1 is *strictly less* than the floor of 2.

Comment: @amWhy - no, @hardmath is correct, I missed this edge case

Comment: @hardmath: sorry 'bout that, hardmath: I didn't ready YOUR comment carefully!  I'll delete my earlier comment. @Thomas: Thanks, for clarifying...

Comment: Here's a proposed fix.  It may strike one as counterintuitive since it relies on floor of $l$ and ceiling of $r$.  The open interval $(l,r)$ contains an integer if and only $l \lt r$ and $( \lceil r \rceil - \lfloor l \rfloor ) \geq 2$.

Comment: @hardmath: Is $l<r$ redundant here?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant!  You only need to retain it if you weaken the latter inequality to include the closed interval with integer endpoint cases (by disjunction).

Answer (score 2):

I would go with
$$
P = (|x|>1) \vee(\lceil l\rceil \leq r \wedge LI)
\vee  (l \leq \lfloor r\rfloor \wedge RI)
$$
Checking $|x|>1$ first, that is, $r-l>1$, is quite a good idea for when implementing this as an algorithm, chances are this condition will be true most of the time anyway, and with a good branch prediction the algorithm only costs one subtraction and one comparison, which makes it very fast.

---

The only trouble is it doesn't work for $x=\,].9,1.1[$... you need one extra logical summand,
$$
P = (|x|>1) \vee (LI \wedge \lceil l\rceil \leq r)
\vee  (RI \wedge l \leq \lfloor r\rfloor )
\vee (\lceil r\rceil - \lfloor l\rfloor =2)
$$
ok, now it's longer that your original proposal... not so nice. It should still be faster as an algorithm, though.

---

$LI \wedge \lceil l\rceil \leq r$ means: if the left border value is inclusive, it's sufficient to know if the number next to the right side of $l$ is in the interval, that is, to know that this number is not further to the right than $r$.

Comment: Could you please explain what the second and the third clauses mean?

Answer (score 0):

$$
(\lfloor l(x) \rfloor \neq \lfloor r(x) \rfloor) \vee (LI(x) \wedge \lfloor l(x) \rfloor = l(x)) \vee (RI(x) \wedge \lfloor r(x) \rfloor = r(x))
$$